# java gc free the application

Tags: java, tomcat, garbage-collection

Using jmx and monitoring a web application, I notice when th GC (G1) is runnig , all threads are freezed, and the application does not responde. I configured the tomcat jvm in like this:

```
-Xms2048m
-Xmx2048m
-XX:NewSize=512m
-XX:MaxNewSize=512m
-XX:PermSize=512m
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
-XX:+DisableExplicitGC
-Xss2m
-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
-XX:+UseG1GC
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8338
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=true
-Dhazelcast.logging.type=slf4j
```

The application does not respond when the used heap memory reach the max limit (2GB) and the GC deeply work on memory. After the gc work the used heap goes down to 300Mb. Is it possibile to setup a different way to work for the GC? This is a big problem for my application because I use hazelcast and jgroups and every time the gc works, it cause a paartition of the cluster.

Some special libraries that I use in this web application:
1) hazelcast 1.9.4
2) akka 0.10
3) jersey 1.2

Comment: Are you using a 32bit JVM/JDK? Coz if so the maximum allocatable memory is 2 Gigs, so you might over do it there with Xms2048m (that tries to allocate 2 Gigs for head from start)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem may be as simple as the fact that you need `-XX:UnlockExperimentalVMOptions`, since (AFAIK) G1GC is still considered experimental.

---

There are a variety of other experimental, HotSpot-specific JVM args you can play around with if that doesn't do the trick:

- `-XX:+UseParallelGC`
- `-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC`
- etc...

See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/gc-tuning-6-140523.html.